# alert or setTimeout after document.writeln

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have this problem on Firefox Version 27.0.1
when I use

```
document.writeln('whatever');
```

I can't use a simple setTimeout function or even an alert.
I can show an alert Before the previous piece of code but not after
**this works:**

```
alert('hello');
document.writeln('whatever');
```

**This does not work:**

```
document.writeln('something');
alert('blah...');
```

in the firebug console it says:

> NS_ERROR_XPC_SECURITY_MANAGER_VETO:

**This does not work either:**

```
document.writeln('text');
setTimeout(function(){
    alert('quak');
    document.writeln('000');
}, 1000);
```

There is no error in the console but nothing happens, actually no code inside ***setTimeout()*** will run before or after a ***document.writeln()***... or ***document.write()*** but it works if I comment or delete those lines

I've tested this in Google chrome there's no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*document.writeln* (or *document.write*) is overwriting all of the document's content. therefor everything you will write below that line becomes irrelevant.

If you want to **add** text to an existing document, use

```
var text = document.createTextNode("text");
document.body.appendChild(text);
```

Comment: Hello Omer
1. What is this error: NS_ERROR_XPC_SECURITY_MANAGER_VETO? 
2. Why does it work in chrome?
3. document.createTextNode("text") doesn't seem to do anything.
thanks.

Comment: its just asking the document object to create a text node, but does not adds it to the document. Will update my answer with full code example that also adds it to the document.

Comment: it might work in chrome due to implementation differences with other browsers. but anyway document.writeln is not the way to achieve what you're looking for. I would suggest to ask a new question about this error (or search for an existing answer). Oh, and if this helps you, help me by accepting the answer  (clicking the empty check mark) :)